# NIntegrate has a memory leak

Tags: numerical-integration, bugs, memory

**Bug introduced in 6.0 and fixed in 10.2.0**

---

`NIntegrate` uses memory and does not release it. For long loops with `NIntegrate`, memory goes up and computation slows down dramatically.
Consider this specific example that uses 40 MB:

```
NI[z_?NumericQ, b0_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[E^-Abs[(y - z)], {y, -b0, b0}]
m1 = MemoryInUse[];
For[i = 1, i < 10000, i++; NI[RandomReal[], .5]] // AbsoluteTiming
m2 = MemoryInUse[];
m2 - m1
```

Result:

> ```
> {117.606048, Null}
>
> 40405872
> ```

How can we make `NIntegrate` release the memory?

Comment: seems like you  had a good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32069961/1004168

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is not about the one-shot memory usage of loading the package(s) of NIntegrate[]. It is about the use of memory after each execution of NIntegrate[].  stackoverflow.com/a/32069961/1004168 has exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 18):

The memory leak in `NIntegrate` is a bug and has been fixed as of version 10.2.0. Earlier versions would lose around 720 bytes per evaluation for this example, which could not be recovered without restarting the kernel.

`ClearSystemCache[]` should be used to make sure the memory is released. Using version 10.2:

```
NI[z_?NumericQ, b0_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[E^-Abs[y - z], {y, -b0, b0}];
NI[RandomReal[], .5]; (* NIntegrate autoloading *)
m1 = MemoryInUse[];
For[i = 1, i < 1000, i++; NI[RandomReal[], .5]; ClearSystemCache[]];
m2 = MemoryInUse[];
m2 - m1

(* -12744 *)
```

Also, if generating many outputs, it may be useful to set `$HistoryLength = 0` or another small number.

We can evaluate the following to test whether the `NIntegrate` call leaks any memory:

```
Block[{$HistoryLength = 0}, ClearSystemCache[]; 
 Take[Table[before = MemoryInUse[]; 
   NIntegrate[E^-Abs[y - RandomReal[]], {y, -.5, .5}]; 
   ClearSystemCache[]; MemoryInUse[] - before, {10000}], -20]]
```

Version 10.2.0 shows no leak,

```
(* {0, 0, 0, 0, -64, 64, 0, 0, -64, 64, 0, 0, -64, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

while version 10.1.0 does

```
(* {656, 720, 656, 592, 720, ..., 656, 656, 656, 656, 656, 656} *)
```

Comment: Does ClearSystemCache basically take care of the problem on pre 10.2 versions?

Comment: Just checking in v9 `ClearSystemCache[]` cuts the leak about in half, but it is still there ( about 1.2 kb/eval with `ClearSystemCache[]` in the loop )

Comment: @march No, it wouldn't help as there is a genuine memory leak in earlier versions. I've edited the answer to clarify this.

Comment: Indeed, ClearSystemCache[] releases only 1/2 of the memory on my Mathematica 10.0. It will not solve my problems as I have to use a loop that is very intensive in NIntegrate[]... Is there a version or option of NIntegrate that does release the memory? (I wish I should not re-program the function...)

Comment: If you have a simple integral (not requiring adaptive sampling, etc) you can implement your own integration using Simpsons rule or some such. That's likely a good approach for this specific example.  ( in the simple case its only a few lines of code )